# Data race when reading field from struct value passed by value

Tags: go, race-condition

Why does golang race detector complains about the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Counter struct {
    value int
    mtx     *sync.Mutex
}

func NewCounter() *Counter {
    return &Counter {0, &sync.Mutex{}}
}

func (c *Counter) inc() {
    c.mtx.Lock()
    c.value++
    c.mtx.Unlock()
}

func (c Counter) get() int {
    c.mtx.Lock()
    res := c.value
    c.mtx.Unlock()
    return res
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    counter := NewCounter()
    max := 100
    wg.Add(max)

    // consumer
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < max ; i++ {
            value := counter.get()
            fmt.Printf("counter value = %d\n", value)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }()
    // producer
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < max ; i++ {
            counter.inc()
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

When I run the code above with `-race` I'm getting the following warnings:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0420042b0 by goroutine 6:
  main.main.func1()
      main.go:39 +0x72

Previous write at 0x00c0420042b0 by goroutine 7:
  main.(*Counter).inc()
      main.go:19 +0x8b
  main.main.func2()
      main.go:47 +0x50

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      main.go:43 +0x167

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      main.go:49 +0x192
==================
```

If I change `func (c Counter) get() int` to `func (c *Counter) get() int` then everything is working fine. It turns out that the receiver type for `get()` function should be a pointer. And I'm confused why that is. I'm aware of "-copylocks" but in this case `mtx` is a pointer, not value. If I change 'mtx' to be value and run program with `vet -copylocks` I get this warning:

> main.go:23: get passes lock by value: main.Counter contains sync.Mutex`

That makes sense.

*note:* This question is not about how to implement thread safe counter

[link to playground code](https://play.golang.org/p/di_OywyU9z)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The race is because of the value receiver for the `get()` method. In order to call the `get()` method, a copy of the struct must be passed to the method expression. The method call without the syntactic sugar looks like:

```
value := Counter.get(*counter)
```

Copying the struct entails reading the `value` field, which happens before the method can take the lock, which is why the race is reported on the line of the method call, rather than within the method.

This is why changing the receiver to a pointer receiver will fix the issue. Also, since all receivers need to be pointers, the `mtx` can be left as a `sync.Mutex` value so it doesn't need to be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

As @JimB points out, in the case of the `get()` method a copy is passed in which case
the field value is read first and then copied, without any locking and since the
same variable is mutated in `inc()`, the race is detected.

To further illustrate this point, you could also change the type of the field `value`
to a pointer i.e. `value *int` in which case you should no longer see a race as now
only the pointer is copied and not the underlying value. That said, to make intentions
clearer, it is cleaner to change the `get()` receiver type to be a pointer.

Here is a good wiki around the same - https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type

A brief commentary on methods:
https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values